# GCE: Health check for an unmanaged instance group or a single instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

is it possible to create a health check for an individual instance (GCE), which is not part of any instance group?

If I look at adding it to a "unmanaged instance group", is it then possible to create a health check for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a health check on my single VM on GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766398/how-to-set-a-health-check-on-my-single-vm-on-gcp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#overview) health checks work together with load balancing, you can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#method) to have a detailed information about how health checks work.

Usually, this health checks applies to an [instance-group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups) for auto healing, so it's not possible to apply a health check for a single instance.

Comment: Yes, that's what it seemed like to me too after googling some more after I posted - that Google Cloud's health checks are tied to auto-scaling and available for load-balancers and managed instance-groups only (and have no meaning for single instances probably). Thanks for your inputs.